# mouse driver in kernel c++, How to create and use it?

Tags: c

I am creating a c++ kernel project, do you know how to make a cursor that when we run the code it appears the cursor even though I disabled windows or macos mouse driver. I thank you in advance!.

Comment: I think asking how to write a mouse driver is too broad for Stack Overflow

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Mouse_Input